# Android app halt prcess when phone goes sleep

Tags: android, delphi-10.3-rio, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am making a simple Android app that monitors a server status and sends an SMS when something is wrong.  It is working fine when the phone is awake, but as soon as the phone goes to sleep, the app sort of freezes immediately.  How to make the app continue to do its job when in sleep?

Android version is 5.1.1

Comment: You need to create a process and raise its priority to foreground [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057958/how-to-keep-application-awake-in-background).

Comment: thanks for the lead. Took me a while to understand that I have to create the unit as androidapi.jni.powermanager is not included during the Delphi CE installation.  However, use the powermanager unit from https://github.com/FMXExpress/Firemonkey/blob/master/Embarcadero/XE7/ObjectPascal/Google%20Glass/Androidapi.JNI.PowerManager.pas which I think is the official one from Embarcadero (for XE7).

Comment: My app seems to be working.  However, my android phone screen is awake all the time, which makes the phone quite hot after leaving for more than 30mins, not to mention the battery drain.  I could have just set the "stay awake" in Android's developer's option if I wanted to keep the phone always awake.  So I guess this is just a temporary solution.